# How to stack two legends together?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I drew the following graph using `matplotlib`:[image]

The code used is as follows:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# Generate data
x = np.linspace(0, 10, 10, dtype=float)
x_mid = x[:-1] + np.diff(x) / 2.0
y = np.random.rand(len(x) - 1) * 100
yerr = np.random.rand(len(x) - 1) * 20
# Plot
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot()
ax.errorbar(x_mid, y=y, yerr=yerr, color='blue', fmt='o', markersize=10, label='Data')
ax.stairs(y, x, baseline=None, color='blue', linewidth=2, linestyle='solid', label='Data')

ax.legend()

plt.show()
```

I encountered difficulty in generating Legend. Although I can use `Line2D([0], [0], marker='|', ls='-', c='blue', markersize=16, markeredgewidth=16)` to generate a crosshair, but it does not have a dot in the middle.

I cannot generate a crosshair with a dot in the middle.  How can I achieve my goal? It is feasible to superimpose a dot in the middle of the crosshairs generated by Line2D, but how to operate it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the latest matplotlib versions, if you combine legend handles into a tuple, they get drawn on top of each other.

For tuples, matplotlib automatically uses [`HandlerTupple`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/legend_handler_api.html#matplotlib.legend_handler.HandlerTuple) as legend handler, with default parameters.  The [legend guide](https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/intermediate/legend_guide.html) contains a few examples of different options.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.lines import Line2D
import numpy as np

# Generate data
x = np.linspace(0, 10, 10, dtype=float)
x_mid = x[:-1] + np.diff(x) / 2.0
y = np.random.rand(len(x) - 1) * 100
yerr = np.random.rand(len(x) - 1) * 20
# Plot
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
bars = ax.errorbar(x_mid, y=y, yerr=yerr, color='blue', fmt='o', markersize=10, label='Data')
stairs = ax.stairs(y, x, baseline=None, color='blue', linewidth=2, linestyle='solid', label='Data')

vertical_handle = Line2D([0], [0], marker='|', ls='', 
                         c=bars[0].get_color(), markersize=22, markeredgewidth=bars[0].get_markeredgewidth())
ax.legend(handles=[(bars, stairs, vertical_handle)], labels=['combined'])
plt.show()
```

[image: combining elements in the legend]